# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (-1 for 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the error 'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (-1 for 0..1)' and I don't know, how to fix that, since I don't know how to pass -1 arguments to a function.

This is the code, which causes the problem.

```
obj = MyObjectClass.new({var_a: cnt, var_b: 0, var_c: 0})
```

This is the initializer of the MyObjectClass.

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  if attributes
    @skip_dirty_tracking = true
    self.attributes = attributes
    @skip_dirty_tracking = false
  end
  yield self if block_given?
end
```

In most cases I get a correct object, but I've got this error twice from the production system.

Backtrace in errbit shows

> my_object_class:59 → initialize

Can someone explain to me how I can force this error?

Comment: `yield` expects a block. It should give a "no block passed" error.

Comment: That's strange, it should not happen. What Ruby version ? What is value of `cnt` ?

Comment: ruby 2.2.2 and it's an positiv integer